# Output of array is as list not as 1D array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write down a very simple lines to have an 1D array, however, the output is not as expected, it's correct but with word array in front of each 5 elements, I attached the code:

```
import numpy as np


 c=np.array([[1,11,21,31,5],[4,14,24,34,5],
             [7,17,27,37,5],[31,41,51,61,5],[34,44,54,64,5],
             [37,47,57,67,5],[61,71,81,91,5],[64,74,84,94,5], 
            [64,74,84,94,5],[64,74,84,94,5], 
              [64,74,84,94,5]
             ,[64,74,84,94,5],[64,74,84,94,5],[64,74,84,94,5], 
               [64,74,84,94,5], 
              [67,77,87,97,5]])
  s=np.array([4,3,2,1])
  r_max=np.max(s)
  d  =    []
  x=4
  for I in range(x-1,-2,-2):
      for J in range(r_max-s[I]):
          d=[d,c[r_max*I-J+3]]
    
  print(d)
  # Output: [[[[[[[[], array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5])], array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5])], array([64, 
            # 74, 84, 94,  5])], array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5])], array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5])], 
             # array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5])], array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5])]
  # expected output same numbers but as 1D array as the following:
    #[67, 77, 87, 97, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5,67, 77, 87, 
    # 97,  5,64, 74, 84, 94,  5,64, 74, 84, 94,  5]]
```

Comment: What is el_con?

Comment: What is "word array"?

Comment: @EwanBrown Thank you for your reply, I just edited the question, now el_con is c

Comment: @ScottHunter
word array is appeared in the output 
I do not know what is it ?? I mean I know it's the type of the output, but I need to have a normal output without that words

Thank you again

Comment: d is a python list, and you repeatedly append numpy arrays to this python list.  Each of those arrays prints out using the word `array`.

Comment: @FrankYellin
Thank you for your feedback, but may I ask how could I avoid this, and have a normal output array ?

Comment: I really don't know what your code is supposed to be doing.  That nested inner loop is incredibly confusing.  But as a start, you want the inner statement to be `d.append(c[....])`.  This will give you you a flat list of arrays.  Make sure each of those arrays contains precisely the elements you want.  Then use `numpy.concatenate` to concatenate the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `list.append` instead:

```
In [373]:   d  =    []
     ...:   x=4
     ...:   for I in range(x-1,-2,-2):
     ...:       for J in range(r_max-s[I]):
     ...:           d.append(c[r_max*I-J+3])
     ...: 
In [374]: d
Out[374]: 
[array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5]),
 array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5]),
 array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5]),
 array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5]),
 array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5]),
 array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5]),
 array([64, 74, 84, 94,  5])]
In [375]: np.array(d)
Out[375]: 
array([[67, 77, 87, 97,  5],
       [64, 74, 84, 94,  5],
       [64, 74, 84, 94,  5],
       [64, 74, 84, 94,  5],
       [67, 77, 87, 97,  5],
       [64, 74, 84, 94,  5],
       [64, 74, 84, 94,  5]])
```

When you collect `numpy` arrays in a list, the display includes the word `array`.  It's telling us that the list contains arrays.  The elements of the `d` list are all the same shape, so `np.array` can produce a nice 2d numeric array.

With `d=[d,c[r_max*I-J+3]]` you have collected the same arrays, but in a deeply nested list of lists.  That cannot be turned into a multidimensional array.

When printing objects, python does not throw in random words like 'array' or brackets.  Those are produced by the objects themselves, and tell something about their identity and structure.  Learn to read that information.  Don't skimp on the basic python and numpy reading.

### 1d expectation

That 2d array can be turned into a 1d one with `ravel`:

```
In [376]: np.array(d).ravel()
Out[376]: 
array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74,
       84, 94,  5, 67, 77, 87, 97,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,
        5])
```

Another option is to use `extend` when collecting the arrays in `d`:

```
In [377]:   d  =    []
     ...:   x=4
     ...:   for I in range(x-1,-2,-2):
     ...:       for J in range(r_max-s[I]):
     ...:           d.extend(c[r_max*I-J+3])
     ...: 
In [378]: d
Out[378]: 
[67,
 77,
 87,
 ...
 94,
 5]
In [379]: np.array(d)
Out[379]: 
array([67, 77, 87, 97,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74,
       84, 94,  5, 67, 77, 87, 97,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,  5, 64, 74, 84, 94,
        5])
```

`hstack` could also be used with the original `d`.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, and accurate explanation, 
actually now, I would like to apply the following line :
    c[r_max*I-J+3]]=[]
I would like to delete all these rows from the c matrix ?

Comment: Please share it an an answer, so I could accept it 

Thank you again

Comment: `c[r_max*I-J+3]]` selects a row from `c`, it's a `view`.  `d` collects these views.  You can't delete 'rows' from `c` by assigning `[]`.  These aren't lists.    You could collect the `r-max*I-J+3` values, and use `np.delete` to make a new array that omits those.

Comment: Thank  you for your comment, 
you mean I collect every index for r-max*I-J+3 and then assign np.delete ??
can not I find another easier and faster way ??

Thank you,

Comment: What's wrong with my suggestion?  Doing one `delete` is faster than doing a bunch of smaller ones.  I suspect you'll be happier doing a pure list task, starting with `c = c.tolist()`.  Using `numpy` for this "row" selection is not making life any easier or faster.

Comment: Do apologize, I do misunderstood you, I am new to python, so forgive me 
you meant the following commands:
c=c[r_max*I-J+3].tolist()
f=np.delete(c)

However, I got the "_delete_dispatcher() missing 1 required positional argument: 'obj'"

Again, thank you so much ,

Answer (score 0):

`d=[d,c[r_max*I-J+3]]`, here you're adding a list as an element.

If you want to `merge` 2 list, you can do: `d = d + list(c[r_max*I-J+3]])`.

You can also use `np.concatenate`: `d = np.concatenate((d, c[r_max*I-J+3]])` (Dont forget to modify the `d` definition with `d = np.array([])`

Comment: Thank you so much ,